# Edit CSS using Dart

Tags: html, css, dynamic, dart

Can I edit a HTML-tag's CSS using DART?

I have done some searching but I couldn't really find out how to do it, or if it even is possible.

The reason to do this because I would like to change a button's location on a page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change or view css properties through `Element.style`. The `Element.style` is an instance of [`CssStyleDeclaration`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-dom-html.CssStyleDeclaration). You can do the following:

```
Element element = document.querySelector("div")
  ..style // edit any of the properties of this variable
  ..style.background = "orange";
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like

```dart
var el = document.querySelector('.somediv'); 
// or '#someid' or other CSS selector to get hold of an element
el.style.color = 'blue';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the dart class CssStyleSheet which can grab a sheet and delete, insert and add rules.  You need to know the index of the rule in the style sheet.